# Google maps integration with webgl earth

Tags: google-maps, webgl-earth

i want to mask google map over webgl earth globe , so currently am gathering data to start , so i come across ( http://examples.webglearth.com/#opposite )

webglearth api is good but documentation is poor , so i explore through its examples and i found that bing maps are integrated with it , so i wonder can i link google maps with webglearth ,  like when i zoom through webgl earth globe and then google maps load with it .  so can anybody have any idea that with webgl earth google map integration is possible or not because there is no bing map api key mentioned or data source mentioned in its examples , which is strange to me because in certain examples there are using bing maps and open streetmap

Comment: Please check this link https://github.com/ashutoshdev/GoogleEarthbyKML may be it will be helpful for you .
Thanks

Comment: am new to KML , my task is to create customize google earth globe like that www.cybermap.kaspersky.com/    ... so can you help me by giving directions ,   so that when i zoom through custom globe and after few zoom level i load google maps satellite view , so that will be possible or not !    help will be appreciated

Comment: Yes ,Exactly you can do  .Please open this link https://github.com/ashutoshdev/GoogleEarthbyKML    .Now you can download the code and check it . which one I have  made .